# How to derive the following Matrix form of the ellipse equation?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, conic-sections

In convex optimization book (By Stephen Boyd) it is mentioned that an set of points which is bounded by an elliptical shape (and hence ellipsoid) can be written as follows $$\{x| (x-x_c)^{T}P^{-1}(x-x_c)\leq r\}$$ where $P^{-1}$ is some positive definite matrix. The general expression for the ellipse in 2 dimension is as follows $$\frac{(x-x_c)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-y_c)^2}{b^2}=h$$ I want to know how derive the first equation from the second equation. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong if think that your last expression is the *general* form of an ellipsis. Howver, given such an ellpsis, the region bounded by it is$$\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\middle|\,\frac{(x-x_c)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-y_c)^2}{b^2}\leqslant h\right\}$$and this set is equal to$$\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\middle|\,\begin{pmatrix}x-x_c&y-y_c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac1a&0\\0&\frac1b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x-x_c\\y-y_c\end{pmatrix}\leqslant h\right\}.$$

Comment: thank you for your answer. What was wrong about that general form. Can you write in in $n$ dimensional case. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: @FrankMoses What's wrong is that what you think that it's the general expression only provides ellipsis whose symmetry axis are horizontal and vertical. Then general form is\begin{multline}a x^2-2 a x_c x+b y x+c y x-b y_c x-c  y_c x+a x_c^2+d y^2+\\+d y_c^2-b  x_c y-c x_c y+b x_c y_c+c  x_c y_c-2 d y y_c\leqslant k,\end{multline}where $k>0$ and $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$ are such that $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is positive definite ($\iff a>0\text{ and }\det\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)>0$).